# How do I make my modal close in x seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ReactJS and a Bootstrap modal. I can open the modal just fine, but I would like it to close after 3 seconds.

I tried setTimeout as you can see below, but it doesn't close. I gave setTimeout a callback of handleClose, but after console logging, I can see that handleClose is not being called.

Here is the ItemDetailView Component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from 'reactstrap';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/addToCartAction';
import './ItemDetailView.css';
import ItemAddedModal from './ItemAddedModal';


class ItemDetailView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    }
    // this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  };

  // toggle() {
  //   this.setState({
  //     modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen
  //   });
  // };

  handleOpen = () => {
    console.log("Cart Open", this.state.modalOpen);
    this.setState({ 
      modalOpen: true 
    },() => {setTimeout(this.handleClose(), 3000)});
    // setTimeout(this.handleClose(), 3000);
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false 
    });
    console.log('handleClose fired!')
  };

  addToCartHandler = () => {
    this.props.addToCart(this.props.card);
    console.log('addToCart++', this.props.quantity);
    this.handleOpen()
    // this.setState({
    //   modalOpen: true
    // });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.title) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="detail-view-wrapper">
        <Card className="text-center detail-view-card">
          {/* <CardImg top width="100%" src={"/" + this.props.img} alt={this.props.title} /> */}
          <CardImg className="detail-view-img" top width="100%" src={"/" + this.props.img} alt={this.props.title} />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle className={"card-title"}>{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle>${this.props.price}</CardSubtitle>
            <CardText>{this.props.description}</CardText>
            {/* <SvgIcon className="cart-icon" onClick={() => this.addToCartHandler()} >
              <AddShoppingCart />
            </SvgIcon> */}
            <button className= "add-to-cart-button" onClick={() => this.addToCartHandler()}>Add To Cart</button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
        <ItemAddedModal open={this.state.modalOpen} toggle={this.toggle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  if (!state.data.cardData) {
    return {
      title: null,
      img: null,
      description: null,
      price: null
    }
  }
  const card = state.data.cardData[state.card.id]
  return {
    card: card,
    title: card.title,
    id: card.id,
    img: card.img,
    description: card.description,
    price: card.price,
    quantity: 0
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addToCart })(ItemDetailView);
```

Here is the ItemAddedModal:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, ModalHeader } from 'reactstrap';
import './ItemAddedModal.css';

class ItemAddedModal extends React.Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
          <Modal className="item-added-modal" isOpen={this.props.open} toggle={this.props.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
            <ModalHeader className="item-added-modal-header">
              <p className="item-added-modal-p">Item Added To Cart</p>
            </ModalHeader>
          </Modal>
        </div>
    )
  };
}
export default ItemAddedModal;
```

Comment: Are you sure `toggle` is being called but `handleClose` is not? I would expect that if `toggle` is called, `handleClose` would also be called, but then get `TypeError: this.setState is not a function`.

Comment: Did you make sure to call toggle function you pass inside of the `ItemAddedModal`? Still no logs?

Comment: Are you sure `toggle` is invoked? It looks like you're opening the modal with `addToCartHandler` which doesn't set the timeout

Comment: can you show the `ItemAddedModal ` code?

Comment: Ok I edited the original post to include both components. You guys were right, toggle was not even being called so I commented it. As you can see I tried a few of the suggestions. The setState solution below is in effect now and I am getting the console log "handleClose fired" but the modal no longer shows. I guess that means the sequence is firing but there is another problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! I was adding parentheses after handleClose: `setTimeout(this.handleClose(), 3000);` but should be `setTimeout(this.handleClose, 3000);`. Thanks a lot for all of your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform an action after a state is set, we need to pass a callback to setState.

```
 this.setState({
  modalOpen: true
},()=>{
console.log(this.state.modalOpen);});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried your callback and it seems to be connecting according to the console logs it is getting all the way to handleClose, but the modal no longer shows at all.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! I was adding parentheses after handleClose: `setTimeout(this.handleClose(), 3000);` but should be `setTimeout(this.handleClose, 3000);`. Thanks a lot for all of your help guys!